# Get event message associated with event

Tags: outlook, office365, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

what is the relationship between [event](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/event) and [event message](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/eventmessage)

How do I get event message associated with event?

using `event.id` in [get event message](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/eventmessage_get) i get `404 NOT FOUND`

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages/<Event ID>
```

returns

```json
{
    "error": {
        "code": "ErrorItemNotFound",
        "message": "The specified object was not found in the store.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "59e0ce99-6aeb-4ad8-b5bc-d498d375538f",
            "date": "2018-07-10T08:01:48"
        }
    }
}
```